# Delphi - TNetHTTPClient - CustomHeaders

Tags: delphi, custom-headers

I try create a wrapper for HTTP calls as a Dynamic Library and I have come this far I am able to add Header and PostData, however, I need to add some special headers which look like this:

```
NetHTTPClient1.CustomHeaders['HeaderName1[HeaderName2]'] := 'HeaderValue';
```

I use this to add "regular" headers

```
NetHTTPClient1.CustomHeaders['HeaderName1'] := 'HeaderValue';
```

I use Delphi 10.4 CE on Windows 10 Pro x64...

Any thoughts / ideas / solutions are really appreciated .....

Comment: `HeaderName1[HeaderName2]` is not a legal HTTP header name. HTTP header names are defined as `token`s, and the characters `[` and `]` are not allowed in `token`s per RFCs 2616 and 7230. Why do you need this, exactly?

Comment: I have this token (among others of same style) which needs to be sent

ajax_page_state[theme]=pco_theme

Comment: That is not an HTTP header, that needs to be passed in either the url query string or in the post body, depending on what the server is expecting.

Comment: YAY .... what an IDIOT I am ..................  :D

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau I had switched POSTDATA and REQUESTHEADER in my TEST APP calling the DLL :( ........